# Service Broker - Add to queue but don't process till later

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

Our current implementation has a data coming into the system onto a Service broker queue a small amount of processing is performed in case more pertaining data comes in, then a SQL Agent job running every two minutes looks for any data that has reaches its 'time to process' and then adds it to another service broker queue.

Is there a way to instead to add something to a service broker queue but not receive it till 5 minutes time (or 20 minutes, or 1 day depending on the data)

There's the message_enqueue_time so you could technically delay everything in the queue`RECEIVE * FROM queuetable where message_enqueue_time < dateadd(min,-30,getutcdate())`, but there's things that need processing at different times from introduction to the queue.

So I'd like to say this entry doesn't want to be picked up till x time and then this doesn't want to be done till y time(which could technically be a week from now).

Is there any way to do this purely within Service Broker or any other way to make the service (next to) real time instead a pulse of data processing every 2 minutes (and not just run the Agent job more often)

Comment: Have you checked [BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/begin-conversation-timer-transact-sql) ?